# How to set onTouchEvent on my custom component

Tags: android, custom-component, touch-event

[My full code here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzfjn06e5x8lzz3/WordFind.zip)

I'm learning Android development and I'm trying to create a simple word-search game. 
First, I created a LetterTile class, it represents one letter on the screen and this class have the method to draw itself.

Then I created a LetterMap class, which is a matrix of LetterTile (if we use LetterMap(6, 6) it will draw on screen a matrix 6x6 of LetterTile).

Now what I want to do is, when I touch one of the LetterTile object, I can do something with it. At this moment, I can't do that because in the MainGamePanel I initialize the LetterMap object, not LetterTile object.

You can see in my code that if I initialize LetterTile object, I just use the onTouchEvent to handle the problem, but now I don't know how to do with the LetterMap

Did I do something wrong? Or my approach to this game is not correct?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if I understand your code but I think your problem is that the onTouchEvent() of your SurfaceView overrides your onTouchEvent of your LetterTile. In this case I would override the onInterceptTouch() method of your surfaceView. See the link below, perhaps this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191914/set-touchlistener-to-root-view-without-overriding-touchevents-of-child-view. Otherwise you have to give more informations what is happening when you are touching the LetterTile, try to debug and look which breakpoints you are jumping and which not.

Comment: LetterTile and LetterMap that I defined is not View yet. LetterTile is a class (not a View) with method to draw itself on canvas, LetterMap is a object (class) that combine of some LetterTile, the draw method of LetterMap simple call the draw method of each LetterTile . And then in onDraw method of the SurfaceView, LetterMap is draw on the screen (thus draw a matrix of LetterTile). When I touch the LetterTile, I just want it to glow or something indicate that I touched it (I think it's not important), but the importance is how can I touch each LetterTile, not the whole LetterMap

Comment: So you can touch your LetterMap? Is this right? When I look into your code I can't see a TouchEvent for your letterMap. Another question: why you aren't using views? Has this a reason?

Comment: you can create a LetterTile object in MainGamePanel and uncomment the onTouchEvent method of MainGamePanel, after that you can move that LetterTile around,so my code can control separate LetterTile touch event, right?. The problem is LetterTile is a part of LetterMap, but in MainGamePanel I just have LetterMap object, I don't know how to control touch event of EACH LetterTile inside the LetterMap.

Comment: The answer for your second question is : I don't know how to use custom view in this situation (through code), I try this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-custom-views-2/ but they use XML implementation. Sorry if my explanation is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't compile your code before. Now I did this and looked a little more detail in it.

1. When I uncomment your onTouchEvent of your MainPanel and add a LetterTile I can't control the touchEvent as you describe it (I set a breakpoint to the onTouchEvent of you LetterTile, but the debugger doesn't jump to it).
2. I think you have to deal this scenario with Views. Because they give you all the methods you need and so you don't have to implement them on your own. Sorry that I can't solve your problem.

A good beginning is the android tutorial for [custom views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).

Comment: Thank you! But if my LetterTile is a View object, do I need to make LetterMap a ViewGroup object? Or LetterMap is just also a View? Furthermore, how can I initialize LetterTile object in the LetterMap class because the constructor is LetterTile(Context context, AttributeSets attrs)? This is really confuse

Comment: Because my LetterMap is an array of LetterTile so I need to create LetterTile object in the LetterMap class

Comment: In other word, how can I create a custom view dynamically (programamtically)

Comment: When your LetterMap is a ViewGroup you have the possibility to set children Views to it with the method: `addView(letterTile)`. So after you create an instance of LetterMap you can call for a example a method `init()` (this you have to write on your own) where you create your LetterTile and add it to your LetterMap. The LetterMap itself can be added in your Activity with `setContentView(letterMap)'.